# Azure SQL/Mobile Services sync with windows mobile 6.5 clients

Tags: rest, azure, synchronization, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am looking for a way other than sync framework 2.1 based Web Services setup to sync Azure SQL (Main DB) with several Windows Mobile 6.5 (SQL Server CE) based clients. Ideally I would like to use Azure Mobile Service API's to do bi-directional sync using JSON data exchange.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a custom offline sync provider for SQL Server CE, you can use Azure Mobile Services built-in offline sync.

Have a look at this [post](https://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/using-sqlsqlcebased-offline-stores-with-azure-mobile-services/)

Comment: This won't work on windows mobile 6.5 as sqlce 4 is not supported